# Почему не приходят письма на ящики mail.ru?

Tags: php

Сайт на Joomla. Отправка своя на php. На другие ящики (yandex и gmail) письма без проблем приходят. Как я понимаю проблема с заголовками, но что поменять не понимаю... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
  <?  

$email = $_POST['email'];      

$mail_message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Заявка с формы "Подписаться на новости"</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Заявка с формы "Подписаться на новости"</h2>
    <ul>            

        <li>E-mail: ' .$email. ' </li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = "From: Autogate Co \r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$mail = mail('info@autogate-co.ru', 'Заказ', $mail_message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Отправитель должен быть example@вашдомен.ru   Если так не заработает, пишите своему хостингу.

Comment: Ну нормально что письма не доходят )) даже удивлён как ваш хостер не блокирует функцию mail() Если письма даже не попадают в спам папку Mail.ru ,то однозначно ваш IP забанили(в mail.ru) и письма даже не входят на сервера mail.ru Стучите поддержке mail.ru. Если вы работаете на Joomla по какой причине не используете её "идеальный" SMTP ? ))

Comment: Спасибо. Просто вписал в form доменную почту. Я тупой, извините.